# Single Page WP Theme

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm building a WP One Page Theme and I want each page to display on my static front-page.  I would like the user to be able to add/edit content of the page in the Dashboard versus the markup.  When I view the page template the_content() is working as advertised, but when I require the page template on my static front-page, everything else shows up normally but the_content() is blank.  Any ideas??  Thanks!

work.php file

```
//  Work Template Page -- the_content() works perfectly 


<!-- works -->
<section id="works">

    <!-- container -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- row -->
        <div class="row">

            <!-- head -->
            <div class="head big wow bounceIn">
                <h3>Our
                    <span class="blue">Works</span>
                </h3>
                <div class="head-break-line">
                    <span class="head-line-blue"></span>
                </div>

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <h6 class="subtext"><?php the_content(); ?></h6>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

            </div>
```

front-page.php file

```
//  Static Front-Page  --  every thing works, but the_content() is blank on this page

<?php require('work.php'); ?>
```

Comment: And you are sure that the page has any content at all? You could try to output the current post with: `<?php global $post; var_dump($post); ?>` to see if the scope is set to your post in that moment.

Comment: Thanks I misunderstood you yesterday.  You were right.  The post was outside of the scope.  Since I'm using front-page.php as my static and home.php for my posts, when requiring the work.php file to my front-page.php, my post variable is set to 'home'.  I still have a lot of learning to do, obviously.  How do I change the scope to match the post from the work.php file?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are `requiring` the page, but you've closed the loop that supplies the post to you. see here ->

```
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Then you perform

```
<?php require('work.php'); ?>
```

This will never work. You would need to perform the loop again by doing:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

From within your `work.php` file.

Comment: Thanks, but the loop is being performed in the work.php file.  It works perfectly when visiting the work page, but the content is blank if I require it on my front-page.  I hope I'm making sense.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've already done that. My solution uses a specialized page template named "Long Page". By default that page is empty, but I have a set of "Content Templates", that can be attached to a page.

So here is the condition: On the "Long Page" I loop through all the child pages. If the child page uses a "Content Template" it get's displayed.

That is my long page:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Template Name: Long Page
 */

define("IN_LONG_PAGE", true);
$_longpage_elements = array();

get_header(); 
?>

<div class="long_page_wrapper">
    <?php
    // Build the query for child pages
    $args = array(
        'post_parent'   => get_the_ID(),
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($query->have_posts()): while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        // Let's see, if the child pages are actually content pages


        $page_template = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_wp_page_template", true);
        if(preg_match("#(content-templates/ct-)#i", $page_template)){
            $_longpage_elements[] = $post;
        }

    endwhile; endif;

    $query->rewind_posts();

    $num = 0;
    if($query->have_posts()): while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        // We will load the custom templates now


        if(in_array($post, $_longpage_elements)){
            $page_template = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_wp_page_template", true);
            $current_index = array_search($post, $_longpage_elements);
            include(trailingslashit(WP_THEME_PATH).$page_template); 
            $num++;
        }

    endwhile; endif;
    ?>
</div>

<?php
    get_footer();
?>
```

This is an example for a simple content template. I have several for all kinds of purposes (accordions, pricing tables, big images, contact forms, etc. pp.)

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: CT Text
 */

global $post, $current_index, $_longpage_elements; 

/*
 * Make sure this file never gets called alone.
 * If so, we redirect to the post parent/home page
 */
if(!defined("IN_LONG_PAGE")) {
    if($post->post_parent){
        $url = get_permalink($post->post_parent)."#".$post->post_name;
    } else {
        $url = get_bloginfo('url');
    }
    wp_redirect($url, 302);
}

$ct_settings = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_ct_settings", true);
if(!is_array($ct_settings)){
    $ct_settings = array();
}

$ct_style = array();
$background_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'post-thumbnail' );
if(is_array($background_image)){
    $ct_style[] = 'background-image: url('.$background_image[0].')';
} else {
    $ct_style[] = NULL;
}

$z_index = 100 - intval($current_index);
$ct_style[] = "z-index: ".$z_index;

$ct_style_print = 'style="'.implode("; ", $ct_style).'"';

$textbox_wrapper_class = array('span6', 'position-wrapper', 'the_content');

?>

<div <? post_class("ct-wrapper ct-text clearfix"); ?> id="<?=$post->post_name?>" <?=$ct_style_print?>>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="title span12">
                <?php the_title("<h2>", "</h2>"); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="<?=implode(' ', $textbox_wrapper_class)?>" <?=$textbox_wrapper_style_html?>>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a lot of custom stuff in there, so it should not work as copy/paste solution. But it should show a general concept of how such a one page layout is possible. Another solution I have seen is to use a ton of shortcodes. But I like to have my content organized and easily editable.

Comment: Thanks!  I've seen this type of work before.  I'm thinking that if I can get can my way to work, it will be much easier to set up.  Just can't get it to work for me!  I may end up ditching my project and starting again from scratch and do more or less the same thing you are.

Comment: What I love about this approach is the extensibility. If there is a template you need and that isn't there yet, you basically add a page template. I always try to implement stuff "as standard as possible" and this is the most standard way I could think of. Both in terms of code standards and WP UX.

Answer (score 0):

Bear with me...I figured out an easy way to have a wp one page theme.  Not sure if it's the best practice, but it's what I was going for and it's extremely easy to understand.  By the way, I'm converting a html site to a theme...forgot to mention that before.

So here goes...I've required each page individually on my front-page instead of the looping through each page.  I did this so I can place each page where I want it, and customize my nav menu:

```
<?php require('services.php'); ?>
<?php require('work.php'); ?>
<?php require('pricing.php'); ?>
<?php require('team.php'); ?>
<?php require('blog-page.php'); ?>
<?php require('contact.php'); ?>
```

Then, inside each page (services.php, work.php, etc) I have used WP_Query:

```
<?php $your_query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=work' ); ?>
<?php while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post(); ?>

  <?php 
     //  I place all of my static page content below this line
     //  This allows me to use the_title() and the_content() functions  ?>

     <!-- head -->
     <div class="head big wow bounceIn">
        <h3>Our
            <span class="blue"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
        </h3>
        <div class="head-break-line">
           <span class="head-line-blue"></span>
        </div>
           <h6 class="subtext"><?php the_content(); ?></h6>
      </div>
      <!-- .head -->

<?php 
    //  more static content here
?>
```

I then reset the postdata and add a conditional statement to display the footer if somehow someone ends up viewing the page individually:

```
<?php endwhile; 
  // reset post data (important!)
  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php
    if ( is_page( 'work' )  ) {    
        // the page is "work" then, 
        get_footer();
    } else { 
        // don't get footer            
    }   
?>
```

With this method I've used, I now have a wp one page theme and the user can update their page content from the admin screen without botching the rest of the page.